# How to draw a donut chart sparkline using highcharts in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, donut-chart, sparklines

I want to draw donut spakline chart in my react project using highcharts.
how can I do this in react?

this is what I want to drow that show the percentage of a value:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `solid-gauge` series type. For easier use of Highcharts in React use the `highcharts-react-official` wrapper.

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HCMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import solidGauge from "highcharts/modules/solid-gauge";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

HCMore(Highcharts);
solidGauge(Highcharts);

const App = () => {
  const [options] = useState(...);

  return <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />;
};
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-wq2eg?file=/demo.jsx

**Highcharts demo:** https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid